# Create planet with Terrain in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain, procedural-generation

I'm looking to create some procedurally-generated planets in unity.  I'm not looking to make huge, realistic planets, but very small, walkable ones (like Super Mario Galaxy).

I've run into a problem though - Terrain objects cannot be rotated, so I can't really make a sphere out of 6 separate squares.

I've tried importing a hi-res icosphere with limited success.  It's difficult to make look good (even with a high number of faces) when up close.   There's also limited support on terrain-like features on non-terrain objects - like how to blend textures, add grass, or place objects on the surface.

I have seen a few unity store assets that do exactly what I'm requesting, so I know something like this is possible.   I just can't figure out where to start.  I've searched for nearly anything related to the topic and found nothing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a shader that will curve your flat surface, like this:

```
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/26165
```

and here is base code:

```
https://alastaira.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/animal-crossing-curved-world-shader/
```

I have used it while ago and with upgrades it works well.